# Use regular expression to extract whole sentence with decimal number

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

I am trying to use regular expressions to extract a sentence containing the word "R&D". 
My code is

```
**\s[^.?!]*R&D[^.?!]*[?.!]**
```

I expect to get `The third quarter R&D spending was 2.4 million, up approximately 100,000 from Q2 levels. SG&A expenses were 3.4 million, down 200,000 from Q2.`

I got `The third quarter R&D spending was 2.`

Answer (score 1):

You can surround `R&D` with `[\w\W]` to match all alphanumeric and non alphanumeric characters:

```
import re
s = "The third quarter R&D spending was 2.4 million, up approximately 100,000 from Q2 levels. SG&A expenses were 3.4 million, down 200,000 from Q2."
sentence = re.findall('^[\w\W]+R&D[\w\W]+$', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'The third quarter R&D spending was 2.4 million, up approximately 100,000 from Q2 levels. SG&A expenses were 3.4 million, down 200,000 from Q2.'
```

Comment: You shouldn't get the second sentence, don't you ? As far as there no "R&D" in it

Comment: @Marine1 generally speaking yes, however, the OP wanted the entire string in this example. If sentences are truly being analyzed, then the string can be split at `.` and each substring analyzed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Ajax1234! I realize that I did want to capture the second sentence.

Comment: @JingKong glad to help!

Comment: @Ajax1234 Understood, therefore if we added sentences, delimited by a `.` after an `R&D`, they would have been captured as well just as the sentence that followed the one where there was `R&D` was captured? So any sentences following one with an `R&D` would be captured as well as the one carrying it ?